# Port Forwarding for java application to be run as server

Tags: java, networking, serversocket, portforwarding, windows-firewall

I made a UDP client and server program and was able to communicate with them using a private address. I just specified those while creating DatagramSockets.

Now I want my system to act as the server and the client can be any computer which wants to communicate with the server through The Internet.

I haven't done port forwarding in windows or for any router before and now I'm in need of it. So which protocol should I use and which application should I use.

If I manually configured the router and forwarded port for my servers port specified through a socket, but while I was checking for an opening of it the status was not available. Even I checked for firewall and don't know which application to make an exception in windows.

Hope you understood the problem and solve it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

[JSch](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/) is a third party networking library written in Java that you can use to accomplish port forwarding.  See their [examples](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/).